# Extracting a JSON object from a serialized string in C#

Tags: c#, json

Assuming I have a string that looks like this ...

```
string s = "{ \"id\": \"1\", \"name\" : \"Test\" } has other text in the same string";
```

Is there a way, in C#, to extract the JSON part of the text as its own "token" when splitting the string apart?

The goal is very simple. In a string that contains text, and possibly a JSON object, I just wanted to try and separate the text from the JSON so that I could pass one off to the appropriate facility. There is no deserialization needed, there is no validation needed, and there is no need to turn the JSON text into an object. I just wanted to be able to pull the text out.

Comment: You mean do a full parsing, or just find the bit between curly braces?

Comment: Just pull out the part between the braces. I don't want to really do any kind of validation, I just want to separate the JSON from the rest of the string.

Comment: Once I have it separated, I can do what I want to it with deserialization easily enough.

Comment: How would you want the values to be returned. Can you write some "broken code" to show what you intend to do with the result?

Comment: just split it on the last "}"

Comment: Also you can search on the web a Regular expression that matches JSON and then extract the coincidences using `Regex.Match(string)`

Comment: Find `{` , find `}`, pick string in between? Is that not what you have in mind?

Comment: @Floris, yeah, that is essentially what I am trying to do. I was just having trouble getting the Regex for it to work right, so I was trying to find out if there was some trick to it I wasn't understanding. It seems I just lacked the right knowledge of Regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bellow code should do what you are looking for (I tested it):

```
string s = "{ \"id\": \"1\", something:{xx:22, yyy: \"3\"}, \"name\" : \"Test\" } has other text in the same string";
var regexp = new Regex("([{].+[}])");
var match = regexp.Match(s);
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I am trying to do, yes. Thank you very much, give me a moment to run this through some trials and I'll get back to you.

Comment: You need something like `[^\]\}` for the end of expression... You don't want to end on an escaped close-curly-bracket

Comment: This worked flawlessly, it was exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

When you are dealing with json, use a real json parser like [Json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/). Regex is not enough to handle all extreme cases.

For example, suppose a string field which contains `[` and you use Garath's answer. Booom.

```
string s = "{ \"id\": \"1\", \"name\" : \"Test\" }";
var anonymousObject = new { id = 0, name = "" };
anonymousObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(s, anonymousObject);

Console.WriteLine(anonymousObject.name);
```

Other Serializer alternatives:  JavaScriptSerializer, DataContractJsonSerializer .......

Comment: why you think "[" will be a problem? I checked it regexp is still ok. I think his problem was to extract JSON from string and then parse it.

Comment: @Garath before going into the detail of parsing json with regex, can you say *how your code tell the value of , for ex. xx*

Comment: I do not want to parse it, he asked for extraction not parsing

Comment: I agree - how about the case of ` \}` as part of the string, too. Not to mention nested obects. A real tool, not a home grown regex, is a better recommendation. But OP indicated he would use a deserializer after extracting the string between `{}`. But his regex would not always manage that.

Comment: @Garath Try to parse this text with your regex.  `string s = "{ \"id\": \"1\", something:{xx:22, yyy: \"3\"}, \"name\" : \"Test\" } has } other text in the same string";` You can not extract the json from text using regex. Just fix your regex for this case and I will post another case.

Comment: With this case you are right, but you code will fail also as invalid JSON.

Comment: @Garath so OP's question is invalid, he doesn't gets his string from a valid source and seems to try to parse a log file etc.

Comment: @Garath [just for future readers] You can not extract the correct json from an arbitrary text file just using regex. For OP's case if we know text starts with Json object(not a json array) and the remaing text doesn't contain any `}` we can even use `string.LastIndexOf`

Comment: I am not trying to validate the JSON. That is taken care of at the point where the string is written. I just want to be able to separate it from the other text. Parsing is not important.